# React.js equivalent of this.id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a html web-form I would use a JavaScript function like this:

```
<select id="test" onChange="getId(this.id)"> </select>

<script>
   function getId(id){
      document.getElementById(id);
   }
</script>
```

What would the react.js version of something like this be? I tried to do:

```
constructor(){
   super();
   this.HandleAddListener = this.HandleAddListener.bind(this.id);
}
```

and the select option:

```
<select id="test" onClick{this.HandleAddListener.bind}> </select>
```

so how would I try and get this.id?

Comment: You can use `ref`s but it's usually the last resort in React. May I ask what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a declarative (React) way to do the same.

Comment: Usually in React trying to access a DOM node directly is a code smell. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/140350). What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Jordan Running  Thanks for the `XY problem` link  Never knew such a term existed 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the event that event handlers receive:

```js
class {
  HandleAddListener(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `this.refs`. See the [docs about](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html). A doc example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: first post on StackOverflow, i need to learn how use this hahahaha.

Comment: Please, consider including a small explanation of what you have linked to your answer.

Comment: Like on react docs, refs are used to get reference to a DOM node or a component in a React. Refs would return the node we are referencing, isn't it?

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest learning about arrow functions `() => {}`, they will bind the scope for you.

read more:

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881